# Scala-Cats: Validating Map's entries

Tags: scala, validation, scala-cats

Let's say I have:

```
val m: Map[String, Int] = Map("one" -> 1, "five" -> 5, "six" -> 6, "nine" -> 9)
```

and I have two functions:

```
def isNotDivisibleByTwo(i: Int): ValidatedNec[String, Int] = Validated.condNec(i%2!=0, i, s"$i is divisible by 2.")

def isNotDivisibleByThree(i: Int): ValidatedNec[String, Int] = Validated.condNec(i%3!=0, i, s"$i is divisible by 3.")
```

I want a function that gives me:

```
def sanitize(m: Map[String, Int]):Map[String, Validated[NonEmptyList[String], Int]] = ???
```

*i.e.* It should return all the numbers that satisfy the said two functions, and a mapping of all the failing numbers and their associated faults.
*e.g.* For the given list m, I want to get:

```
val result = Map(
  "one" -> Valid(1),
  "five -> Valid(5),
  "nine" -> Invalid(NonEmptyList("9 is dividible by 3")),
  "six" -> Invalid(NonEmptyList("6 is dividible by 2", "6 is dividible by 3"))
)
```

This is what I currently have:

```
import cats.data._

val m: Map[String, Int] = Map("one" -> 1, "five" -> 5, "six" -> 6, "nine" -> 9)

def isNotDivisibleByTwo(i: Int): ValidatedNec[String, Unit] = Validated.condNec(i%2!=0, (), s"$i is divisible by 2.")

def isNotDivisibleByThree(i: Int): ValidatedNec[String, Unit] = Validated.condNec(i%3!=0, (), s"$i is divisible by 3.")


def sanitize(m: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Validated[NonEmptyChain[String], Int]] = {

  m.mapValues{
    i =>
      isNotDivisibleByTwo(i).product(
        isNotDivisibleByThree(i)
      ).map(_ => i)
  }

}
```

But, I am not happy with the way I am "composing" the validations.

How can I do this in the most catsy way?

Comment: Hi Luis, I have posted my attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were so close.
Remember that the correct way to combine multiple **Validates** is using the `Applicative` syntax.

```
import cats.data.{Validated, ValidatedNec}
import cats.syntax.apply._

type ErrorsOr[A] = ValidatedNec[String, A]

def isNotDivisibleByTwo(i: Int): ErrorsOr[Int] =
  Validated.condNec((i % 2) != 0, i, s"$i is divisible by 2.")

def isNotDivisibleByThree(i: Int): ErrorsOr[Int] =
  Validated.condNec((i % 3) != 0, i, s"$i is divisible by 3.")

val map: Map[String, Int] = Map("one" -> 1, "five" -> 5, "six" -> 6, "nine" -> 9)

def sanitize(m: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, ErrorsOr[Int]] =
  m.view.mapValues { i =>
    (
      isNotDivisibleByTwo(i),
      isNotDivisibleByThree(i)
    ).tupled.map(_ => i)
  }.toMap

sanitize(map)
// res: Map[String, ErrorsOr[Int]] = Map(
//   "one" -> Valid(1),
//   "five" -> Valid(5),
//   "six" -> Invalid(Append(Singleton("6 is divisible by 2."), Singleton("6 is divisible by 3."))),
//   "nine" -> Invalid(Singleton("9 is divisible by 3."))
// )
```

However, you may make the code even more general, to work with any number of validations. By using `traverse`.
*(In this case, you do not need any syntax import)*.

```
import cats.data.NonEmptyList

val validations: NonEmptyList[Int => ErrorsOr[Int]] = NonEmptyList.of(isNotDivisibleByTwo, isNotDivisibleByThree)

def sanitize[K, V](map: Map[K, V])
                  (validations: NonEmptyList[V => ErrorsOr[V]]): Map[K, ErrorsOr[V]] =
  map.view.mapValues(i => validations.traverse(f => f(i)).map(_ => i)).toMap

sanitize(map)(validations)
// res: Map[String, ErrorsOr[Int]] = Map(
//   "one" -> Valid(1),
//   "five" -> Valid(5),
//   "six" -> Invalid(Append(Singleton("6 is divisible by 2."), Singleton("6 is divisible by 3."))),
//   "nine" -> Invalid(Singleton("9 is divisible by 3."))
// )
```

---

*The reason why I use `.view.mapValues(...).toMap` is because on **Scala 2.13** `mapValues` is deprecated.*